# MongoError: unknown operator: $search - mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use `search` operator, but I have this error everytime...

```
 MongoError: unknown operator: $search
```

My code is:

```
Cars.find({
  where: {
    MODEL: {
      search: 'BM'
    }
  },
  limit: 7
}, options, function(err, cars) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    cb(err, null);
  }
  if (cars && cars.length > 0) {
    cb(null, cars);
  } else {
    cb(null, 'NO CAR');
  }
});
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

`$search` only exists in Atlas. You can't use it anywhere else.

Your code however doesn't appear to use it (since there isn't a dollar sign before search) thus your actual problem may be something else entirely.

Comment: thank your for your help, but how can I do the same thing like `search` ? to find something without type whole string ? my mongodb version is: 2.2.25

Comment: $text operator exists in non-Atlas MongoDB servers.

Comment: MongoDB 2.2 is not supported by any current driver release, you should upgrade.